# Code First Supress Foreign Key Generation

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

We have a DB with many entities and I am taking an example of three entities Case, Task and Note. Any entity can have a Note and we have decided to go with the following DB design.

```
Case:
  - CaseId
  - Title

Task:
  - TaskId
  - Title

Note:
  - NoteId
  - Desc
  - ParentId (will contain the PK of Case/Task etc but without FK constraint)
```

The POCOs will be as below:

```
Case
{
  CaseId
  Title
  Notes
}

Task
{
  TaskId
  Title
  Notes
}
```

We don't want to have referential constraints and all, as these notes will not be deleted. We can model this using `EDMX` and want to use Code First approach. We have searched SO and looked at the suggestion of polymorphic associations etc. If given this design what is the best way to model using code first? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want code-first to generate/migrate your database?

Comment: Yes, we would want the DB to be generated as per the question.

Comment: You can't model an association that EF won't try to convert to a FK constraint when creating a database. You'll have to join the Notes manually, e.g. in a repository.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use inheritance - it is follows from your description:

```
public class EntityWithNotes
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public Collection<Note> { get; set; }
}

public class Note
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class Case : EntityWithNotes { /* ...*/ }
public class Task : EntityWithNotes { /* ...*/ }
```

...and use foreign key association. Referential constraints are not about deletion only.

Comment: Thanks for the your response Dennis. I would appreciate if you or someone can point us to an approach for the original problem of not having/let ef generating FKs.